# DocuSign C# REST API Attaching documents with signers to existing envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Ones I create a draft envelope with two signers attach to a pdf document. Then try to attach second documents with one signer to the same envelope. The document gets attached but signer is not added to envelop. Please let me know what am I missing here.

**Attach document for same envelop code**

**HttpWeb Request URL**

```
 url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/" + accountID + "/envelopes/" + envelopID + "/documents";
```

**Rest Script**

```
strAttDOCScript = "{ \"status\": \"sent\", \"documents\": [{ \"documentId\": \"" + iDocumentID +"\", \"name\": \"" + strDocumentName +"\", \"documentBase64\": \"" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(AttFile) +"\" }]," +
                "\"recipients\": { \"signers\": [{ \"email\": \"tuanppal@gmail.com\", \"name\": \"Sara Mason\", \"recipientId\": \"3\", \"tabs\": { \"checkboxTabs\": [{ \"tabLabel\": \"sampleCheckbox\", \"xPosition\": \"20\", \"yPosition\": \"20\"," +
                 "\"documentId\": \"2\", \"pageNumber\": \"1\" }], \"signHereTabs\": [{ \"conditionalParentLabel\": \"sampleCheckbox\", \"conditionalParentValue\": \"On\", \"xPosition\": \"80\", \"yPosition\": \"40\", \"documentId\": \"2\", \"pageNumber\": \"1\" }] } }] }}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create a draft envelope to add more documents to it you need to call [EnvelopeDocuments: update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/update) API.  Note that this is a `PUT` method, not a POST like you did when creating the envelope.

If this does not solve your issue then please post the full details of your API request such as endpoint, verb, request body, and exact response so we can inspect (you can redact any private info if needed).

Comment: A comment on your answer was posted as an answer, the links have been updated: "[Envelopes: update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/), [EnvelopeDocuments: updateList](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/updatelist/)"

Answer (score 2):

Using [EnvelopeDocument:Update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/update/), you will add second document in the draft envelope. Once you have added the document in the envelope then you need to call [EnvelopeUpdates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) with query parameter `advanced_update=true`

**URI:**

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?advanced_update=true
```

**Body:**

recipientId value should be the recipientId of the signer whose tabs needed to be added to second document.

```
{
    "status":"sent",
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
                     {
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabs": {
                            "checkboxTabs": [{
                                "tabLabel": "sampleCheckbox",
                                "xPosition": "20",
                                "yPosition": "20",
                                "documentId": "2",
                                "pageNumber": "1"
                            }],
                            "signHereTabs": [{
                                "conditionalParentLabel": "sampleCheckbox",
                                "conditionalParentValue": "On",
                                "xPosition": "80",
                                "yPosition": "40",
                                "documentId": "2",
                                "pageNumber": "1"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: A comment on your answer was posted as an answer, the links have been updated: "[Envelopes: update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/), [EnvelopeDocuments: updateList](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/updatelist/)"